# Attempting to use an enum in template class, so that its values may be manipulated as a linked list

Tags: list, class, templates, enums, nodes

I am attempting to create a queue or linked list that will allow me to manipulate enum values, in this case 10 vegetables, through the list.  At first I followed an example that allowed to manipulate ints and doubles, however now I am very confused. I don't know how replicate this behavior with an enum. Any insight is appreciated.

HEADER FILE

```
#ifndef LISTND_H
#define LISTND_H

template< class NODETYPE > class List; // forward declaration

enum vegetables_t
{
    potato = 1, carrot, broccoli, tomato, onion, celery,
    radish, kale, beet, eggplant
};

template< class NODETYPE >
class ListNode { ... }
```

Main function...

```
void testList( List < class T > &, const char* );

int main()
{

    /*List < enum value > vegList*/
    List < vegetables_t > vegList; 
    testList ( vegList, "vegetable" ); // test integerList

    return 0;
}
```

Attempting to use enum values in testList

Comment: Move your enum out of the class to the file scope.

Comment: If you have an update to your question, edit it. Comments on this site are not suitable for code. If you have compilation errors, post the errors.

Comment: `template <class NODETYPE> class List` makes sense. You can have a list *of* integers or a list *of* characters or a list *of* vegetables or a list *of* lists *of* vegetables. `template <class NODETYPE> class vegetables_t` makes no sense. You cannot have a vegetable of characters or a vegetable of integers.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback... it has proven very resourceful. I will have to read up on template classes more carefully before attempting something like this. Cheers.